# Codename One: Resources Not Being Found in Android Build

Tags: java, android, codenameone, inputstream

I am using Codename One to build a little game. My game works in the simulator, however, whenever I run an Android build of the game, I'm met with

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void java.io.BufferedReader.close()' on a null object reference
```

I used an if statement to simply close an input stream if it is not null but then nothing loads in, which seems to me I am not configuring my resources correctly.

This is how I am loading in my image resources:

```
public static final String DUCKY_ATLAS = "/duckySprite.png";
public static final String LEVEL_ATLAS = "/mapSprite.png";

public static final String START_LEVEL = "/levelOne.png";
public static final String OBSTACLE_SEQUENCES = "/levelSequences.png";

//method to pull Image from file 
public static Image getSpriteAtlas(String file) {
    Image img = null;
    try {
        InputStream is = CN.getResourceAsStream(file);
        img = Image.createImage(is);
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return img;
}
```

The location of my resources folder looks like : /common/src/main/resources

There is also no nesting within it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the files in the folder match the case you use as even the file names are case sensitive. I suggest showing the specific file name that wasn't found as an error so you'll know which file is missing.

Other than that you should use the newer syntax of try-with-resources as part of Java 8:

```
try(InputStream is = CN.getResourceAsStream(file)) {
    img = Image.createImage(is);
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e(e);
    Dialog.show("Error", "Loading file failed: " + file, "OK", null);
}
return img;
```

This removes the need to close. Also, always use `Log.e()` instead of `printStackTrace`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a file using your string filename with path, for example:

```java
File file = new File("res/raw/filename.png");
```

2. Try to use `FileInputStream` like so:

```java
FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(file);
```

Note that `NullPointerException` may happen because of there is no declaration at all.

Comment: This is wrong. It's an answer for Android and that's a Codename One question.